# How do I create respective layers for separate pieces of sculptures?

Tags: modeling, layers

I'm not sure how to use the layer feature for different sculptures in Blender?
Example:

- #1 Sculpture should be on #1 layer, and same for #2 sculpture on #2 layer... Not this way: #1 and #2 sculptures on a same layer at all.
  I'd like to be able to carve #1 sculpture without causing #2 sculpture to act like it's being treated the same way.
- Another Example: Supposedly if I want to be able to create asymmetrical tail on a cat's body, I should be able to do that without it altering the cat's body at all.

I'm trying to figure out a shortcut, or at least how to get it to work...
I've tried ask this question on Blender Discord, and Reddit (which I copy-pasted most of my question into here).

- Then eventually, I got an answer on the discord server that I should try a shortcut command which is Shift + A in the sculpt mode. Which I assume is masking an area (light gray-colored area) on a sculpture to make it only be able to inflate... rest of the sculpture that can't be inflated is dark gray-colored area...
  -- Sam

(#1 Edit: Removed 2nd question; #2 Edit: Thank you for the responses, I appreciate the question you had for me - though I don't think it's the answer at all since it's masking not layers solution.)

- Sam

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. [edit] your question, delete one question and ask it in a new page.

Comment: Ah, Betcha - just corrected my post mistake, removed the other question, I'll ask the 2nd question in a new post, thank you Susu!

Comment: Is the last bullet point an answer? If yes, then please post it below in the answers section.